# Why does contrapositive imply conditional?

Tags: proof-writing

Lets say P implies Q.

Therefore I understand that ~Q implies ~P, because if Q is not true then P can never be true.

However, I don’t get why it’s true the other way round.
For example:
If not B then not A, how do you get that A implies B from that statement.

Comment: If you are in a math class, you can always ask your teacher. Although the topic is short, you can still try to lengthen it for research on the topic. See [Question guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> Note that the relationship between a direct implication and its contrapositive is abstractly symmetric, since the negation of the negation of $P$ is $P$. In more detail, if we take $B = \neg P$ and $A = \neg Q$, then "$\neg B$ implies $\neg A$" is equivalent to "$P$ implies $Q$".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok let’s start with $$\lnot Q\implies \lnot P.$$

Letting $A=\lnot Q$ and $B=\lnot P,$ we can resymbolise this sentence as $$A\implies B.$$

This, as you agree, is equivalent to $$\lnot B \implies \lnot A. $$

Reversing the substitution: $$\lnot\lnot P\implies \lnot\lnot Q, $$ i.e., $$P\implies Q. $$

Comment: Thank you, I get it now.